# How to extract a part of a protein sequence in reverse using Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of protein sequences:

```
VLQSDLYTLSSSVTV
WKLYSKVKPLLNVAR
YNTSLRTMPTMIWTW
GVDFYSTITRARFEE
```

I want to extract only the last 4 residues (last four characters) from the sequences (in reverse order), such as

```
VTVS
RAVN
WTWI
EEFR
```

How to do that with Python code?

Comment: So, you have a string with multiple "words", and you want the last 4 letters of those words, in reverse order?  Or do you have a list of 4 strings?

Comment: What is the data structure you get (can you provide it in Python syntax) and what is the problem you have to do what you describe?

Comment: Your output seems to contradict the stated requirement. You say you want to "...extract...from left to right" but the output is right to left (reversed)

Answer (score 4):

Via a list comprehension:

```
a = ['VLQSDLYTLSSSVTV', 'WKLYSKVKPLLNVAR', 'YNTSLRTMPTMIWTW', 'GVDFYSTITRARFEE']
b = [x[::-1][0:4] for x in a]
```

Each `x` is a string from the list `a`. The portion `x[::-1]` reverses that string. The first four characters of the reversed string are extracted via `...[0:4]`. The list `b` contains each of these results.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "VLQSDLYTLSSSVTV WKLYSKVKPLLNVAR YNTSLRTMPTMIWTW GVDFYSTITRARFEE"
words = s.split()
for word in words:
    print(word[-1:-5:-1])
```

Comment: This doesn't give the desired result, should be ```word[-1:-5:-1]```